# ConnectionPoolTimeoutException when making HTTP Requests from ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice

I have a method making an HTTP call - `putObject(Object obj);`

I am executing it like so:

```
private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 64;

ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
for (Object obj : listOfObj) {
    threadPool.submit(() -> putObject(obj));
}
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

After making ~300 odd calls, few calls to putObject() throw the ConnectionPoolTimeoutException.

If I change the invocation of the method from an ExecutorService to something else (like CompletableFuture), I do not face this problem.

Full exception stack:

```
[junit] org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:286)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:263)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
[junit]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
```

Can anyone shed any thoughts on this? I can't figure it out. Appreciate it.

Comment: What is the THREAD_COUNT?

Comment: Edited the question